# Does the browser hit the network each time it loads the same src for HTML5 video?

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a VIDEO tag loaded with a "src" attribute set to a particular filepath to a video asset. I have an array that stores some number of other filepaths to different video assets. I have a button that, when clicked, instructs the VIDEO tag to load one of the filepaths in the array.

If the VIDEO tag loads an asset that it has already loaded in the past (during this same page session) does it have to go back out to the network and redownload that asset as if it never downloaded it before or will it realize that it has cached this file and just pull the data from the cache?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use HTML5's caching manifest to instruct the browser to load from cache. Read more about it here:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#manifests

Basically, you specify:

```
<html manifest="manifest.cache">
```

and then define what resources are cached in a manifest.cache file:

```
CACHE:
path/to/your/video/file
```

Comment: Hi @BenD! Thanks for the response! I've worked with manifest.cache before, but I always looked at that as more of a tool to use to create web-based mobile apps that can operate offline. My question was really more about the behavior of the browser - I'm wondering if videos work in the same way that images used to... remember that "preload" solution ages ago where you would create a new Image object and give it a URL to an image file?

Comment: As I understand it, the answer is: it depends.  what format? What cache headers are being sent by the server when it sends the file? what browser and version? The advantage of using the cache manifest is that it ensures that the video will always be served from cache.